# celery use redis as broker，but makes a error

Tags: redis, celery

```
[2021-04-06 11:27:56,700: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@172.30.7.4:7000/0
[2021-04-06 11:27:56,723: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-04-06 11:27:57,777: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-04-06 11:27:57,784: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError('Wrong number of response items from pipeline execution',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 208, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py", line 41, in start
    c.connection, on_decode_error=c.on_decode_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 304, in TaskConsumer
    **kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.revive(self.channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 408, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 421, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 611, in declare
    self._create_queue(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 620, in _create_queue
    self.queue_declare(nowait=nowait, passive=False, channel=channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 655, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 532, in queue_declare
    return queue_declare_ok_t(queue, self._size(queue), 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 770, in _size
    sizes = pipe.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3691, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3601, in _execute_transaction
    raise ResponseError("Wrong number of response items from "
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Wrong number of response items from pipeline execution
```

Comment: You need to give more details, not just lines from log... Are you using Redis authentication (token)? What are the versions of Celery, Redis and redis-py that you use?

Comment: Redis：4.1.1,redis-py 3.5.3,Celery 5.0.5 and I am useing Redis authentication.

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade to either latest 4.x or 5.x Celery. I think Celery 4.1.1 depends on version of Kombu that is just too low. I can't remember when did it start to work with Redis authentication...